# Is there any way to fetch Mobile Number of windows phone 10 using c#

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I have created my application in UWP. I need to search current sim and sim Mobile number.
Please help me for find the mobile number using windows phone 10 in c#

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [SmsDevice2.AccountPhoneNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Sms.SmsDevice2#Windows_Devices_Sms_SmsDevice2_AccountPhoneNumber) to get the phone number. From this article,Pay attention of

> This functionality is only available to mobile operator apps and
>   Windows Store apps given privileged access by mobile network
>   operators, mobile broadband adapter IHV, or OEM.

Hence it requires the cellularMessaging capability, a special-use capability, to be declared in the package manifest, so this kind of app can’t be published in Windows Store for normal developer

A relative sample of SMS you can reference [SMS send and receive sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmsSendAndReceive).

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the phone number from the device, whatever its type was, for a simple reason, that the mobile phone number is not stored on the SIM Card.

SIM Card holds contacts, SMSs, and network information along with an ID to link this SIM card to the User phone number.

so, don't try u will not get it from the SIM, but if it was stored manually in the device anyway else, you can get it then.

Comment: But is there any way to get mobile number from window phone because Whats worked on your mobile number right? if it different whatever you type the it will confirm with user.
My point is get mobile number of windows phone 8.1 or 10 in c#